# Google OAuth consent screen stays on "Needs verification" after submission

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My application needs to interact with the Google API's using some specific scopes, so I need to submit it for verification. When doing so, I use the *Prepare for verification* button in the screenshot below.
[image: OAuth consent screen - needs verification]

After completing the form, the toast message “Your app has been submitted for verification” appears and I am redirected to the same screen. However, the status "Needs verification" remains and no change is visible to indicate that my app is in the process of being verified. I am able to repeat the process without any visible change.

I submitted the application for the first time 2 weeks ago, but still no change. Is this a bug in Google's platform? How should we proceed (without having to buy a 100$/month support subscription)?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Details on what types of scopes are required. Internal or External? What type of app? If you are requesting restricted scopes, you most likely will not be approved (except for native android and iOS apps). Read this link in detail: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You can check your app verification status via email;

> Your project's last submitted OAuth consent screen is under review. Additional information about your app, if required, may be requested via email at the email addresses you provided in the Developer contact information section of the Prepare for verification process. Expect the first email within 3-5 days.

You can find more information about this process in the [Oauth Verification documentation](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615#zippy=%2Cverification-in-progress).

If so happens that your app is a "[restricted scope app](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#zippy=%2Chow-long-will-the-verification-process-take%2Chow-do-i-submit-for-verification%2Chow-do-i-determine-if-i-need-to-submit-my-app-for-restricted-scope-verification)" verification may take a few weeks instead of a 3-5 days.

You should have get an email with the confirmation that your app is being verified. If not try again and check your spam folder. If you aren't getting any emails then go to [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) and report a bug.

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of the Issue tracker. I filed a bug report.